# Using ConcurrentBags

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am running some code that uses ConcurrentBags.  I am exploring the IEnumerable functionality.
The code I run is

```
ConcurrentBag<int> bag = new ConcurrentBag<int>();

Task.Run(() =>
{
    bag.Add(42);
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    bag.Add(21);
});
Task.Run(() =>
{
    foreach (int i in bag)
        Console.WriteLine(i);

}).Wait();
```

I expected the code to return 42, but it is returning nothing.
Was my assumption wrong?

Comment: Why are you not putting a `Wait` on your first task? Could it be because the first task is async and you have a race condition? Actually yeah, this is definitely a race condition.

Comment: @eisberg NO NO NO NO NO! Read Jon's answer. This is a race condition, and that is a horrible way to work around the problem.

Comment: @gunr2171 Not to mention it wouldn't solve the problem anyway.

Comment: You may want to look in to a [`BlockingColection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) instead and use [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186.aspx) to pull out of the bag. The behavior is slightly different, but 90% of the time I have found it is the behavior people new to the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace where looking for in the first place when doing stuff similar to you.

Answer (score 4):

You have a race condition, basically. On my machine, this *does* print 42 most of the time - but fundamentally you have two independent tasks: one adding, and one printing. There is *no* guarantee which task will execute its first statement first, as you have no synchronization or coordination between the two tasks.

If you want to ensure that the first `Add` call has completed before you start to iterate over the bag, you'll need to have some coordination.